# Understanding ProviderToken in inject using Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to understand `inject` 's  role in the short-hand approach to `resolve` in Angular.

```js
            {
                path: ':id',
                component: RecipeDetailComponent, 
                resolve: {detail: (route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => inject(RecipeService).getRecipes()[route.params['id']],
                data: () => inject(HttpService).fetchRecipes()                      
            }},
```

We have the short-hand `resolve` key which correct me if I am wrong, but is **not** deprecated. Only the `resolve` interface in services is deprecated. This `resolve` key takes an object where we have custom keys. In the short-hand approach, each key which are **details** & **data** requires us to inject our appropiate services. Now according to the [Angular documentation for inject](https://angular.io/api/core/inject), the appropiate services `RecipeService` and `HttpService` should be of type of `ProviderToken<T>`. But what is `ProviderToken<T>` and what is the `T` and why does the `inject` function return `T`? In the [Angular documentation for ProviderToken](https://angular.io/api/core/ProviderToken), it states that a `ProviderToken<T>` is

> Token that can be used to retrieve an instance from an injector or through a query.

But I never really encountered anything in the Angular documentation that states what a token really is? The code above works perfectly, but I just want to understand the behind the scenes of how the `inject` function works.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've already pointed out (from angular docs)

```
type ProviderToken<T> = Type<T> | AbstractType<T> | InjectionToken<T>;
```

that means that token could be a "class" | "abstract_class" | "new InjectionToken(...)"

RecipeService and HttpService are classes here. So `inject(HttpService)` would search for something provided as `HttpService` in the injection context

what about deprecation - they deprecated class versions of resolvers in favor of much more simple and short function versions.

Comment: Okay, you gave me a good idea about the `inject` function, but just to be sure, the way I used `resolve` is not deprecated right? Or should I change it? thanks

Comment: `resolve: {something: ResolverClass}` is deprecated. you have function in place of class so everything is fine